# FDT for Adobe AIR desktop not launching debugger under Debug conditions

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, fdt

I am using FDT 7 (1.15.240.1795) under Windows 7 with AIR 18 (Flex 4.13.0) for a desktop AIR build. When I run with debug=false, the project launches fine. When I try to launch with debug set to true, FDT does the SWF build, but then sits there without launching the debugger.

Does anyone have a thought about how to see if the adl call is failing in some way, or simply not getting invoked?

Thanks!

-jonathan

Comment: I figured out the issue (sort of). My project depended on several others, and I had recently changed the Flex SDK on those referenced projects. I see that when I corrected the Flex SDK reference on the other projects, then it launched the debugger and it ran fine. What's weird is that after a few rebuilds, it goes back to hanging, so I have to clear out the compiles and then relaunch with debug configurations.

Comment: I celebrated too soon. The debugger starts only when there are no breakpoints set, so effectively it is useless. If there is a breakpoint set, then it goes back to hanging and not launching the debugger. I tried to set a breakpoint while the process was running, but it was not respected. I do notice that the ASC 2.0 compiler is generating a lot of errors (a few 1000) but the application is running fine as far as I can tell.

Comment: Please can you give a few more details about how do you lauch the AIR build. The output of the build console would help to answer your question.

Comment: thanks, I used Kdiff to compare the AIR build with a breakpoint and without a breakpoint. The builds are EXACTLY the same. Here is the console output:

Comment: thanks, I used Kdiff to compare the AIR build with a breakpoint and without a breakpoint. The builds are EXACTLY the same. Here is the good launch build [link](http://eqsim.com/tmp/goodlaunch.txt) and here is the non-launch build [link](http://eqsim.com/tmp/nolaunch.txt). You will see there are a lot of warnings about duplicate references. One thing I wonder about..the compiler is detecting 6500 'errors', but those 'errors' are from files in the projects that are not being compiled, what I mean is that they are in files in folders that I use to make swc's, but not through FDT.

Comment: The StackOverflow comments keep timing out, so I have to add a new comment. My point at the end is that maybe the launcher is getting canceled in the presence of a breakpoint, somehow. The good launch goes through and connects to the AIR debugger (does the trace of the launch in the console, but I didn't add that to the goodlaunch file I posted), but the non-launch just sits there, no output.

Comment: Please attach the workspace log file. For me it is still unclear why the launch fails. Maybe some exception is thrown. You can also try to do a clean before you launch.

Comment: Hi Steffi, my log file isn't writing out any issues when I launch with no breakpoint nor with a breakpoint. I just updated to FDT 1.16.190.1832 and also Java. Still no difference. However, on a virtual machine I have which has the same project, updating like that now allows me to set breakpoints in debug. Very strange!

Comment: Here it is, anyway:
eclipse.buildId=4.3.2.M20140221-1700
java.version=1.8.0_91
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.powerflasher.fdt.product.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product com.powerflasher.fdt.product.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2016-06-11 03:57:35.214
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set

Comment: Since it is working inside the virtual machine I guess your network settings are corrupt somehow. You may switch off your firewall for a moment and verify that port connections are allowed. You may also verify that FDT is running with enough user rights.Also you could try to use the old mxmlc compiler instead of ASC 2.0.